# Asymptotic behaviour of the solution of a PDE

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have the following PDE:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t,r)&=\alpha(r-\beta)\frac{d}{dr}u(t,r)+\alpha u(t,r)\\
u(0,r)=&u_0(r)
\end{align}

where $r\in [0,1]$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed constants in $[0,1]$.

I would like to prove that $\lim_{t\to  +\infty}u(t, r)\equiv \beta$.

What I know about the initial condition is that $u_0(0)=u_0(1)=0$, $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$ and that $\int_0^1 u_0(r)rdr=\beta$.

The equation can be solved trough the characteristic method and the solution is given by

$u(t,r)=u_0((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t})+\beta)e^{\alpha  t}$.

How to prove that $\lim_{t\to +\infty}u(t,r)=\beta, \forall r\in (0,1)$? Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure it's $\int u_0(r)rdr$ not $\int_0^1u_0(r)rdr$?

Comment: You are right, it was a misprint, I modified the text. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you expect that limit? After all, $u\equiv\beta$ does not solve the equation (unless $\alpha\beta=0$). Also, a look at the characteristics reveals that your solution formula needs data from the entire real line, which is outside the domain of the equation. Accordingly, you really need boundary conditions at $r=0$ and $r=1$.

Comment: I have the conditions for $r=0$ and $r=1$, I just added to the text. Thank you!

Comment: I expect that limit because of the nature of my problem and also because my professor said that.

Comment: Sorry, your professor is wrong, or you misquoted him. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by characteristics that you give, is only valid when $(r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}+\beta\in[0,1]$, that is, for
$$ \beta-\beta e^{-\alpha t} \le r \le \beta+(1-\beta) e^{-\alpha t}, $$
an interval of width $e^{-\alpha t}$. Outside that interval, the characteristic will hit one of the boundary conditions at $r=0$ or $r=1$, and so $u(t,r)=0$ at those points.

You should find that $\int_0^1 u(t,r) \,dr = \int_0^1 u_0(r)\,dr=\beta$ (a constant).

Conclusion: The asymptotic limit of the solution as $t\to\infty$ is $\beta\delta_\beta$, where $\delta_\beta$ is a delta function located at $\beta$ (sometimes written $\delta_\beta(r)=\delta(r-\beta)$).

**Edited to add:**
This analysis assumes $0<\beta<1$ and $\alpha>0$. If $\alpha=0$, the solution is of course independent of $t$. And if $\beta=0$ or $\beta=1$, the analysis needs to be changed a bit, but much the same will still hold

**Edit the second:**
Here is a picture of the solution. I chose $u_0(r)=4(r-r^2)$, $\beta=2/3$, and $\alpha>0$. The red graph is the initial condition $u_0$,
blue is the solution for $e^{\alpha t}=2$, and the tallest one (khaki) is for $e^{\alpha t}=4$. The area under each curve is the same in each case.

Also, I removed my totally misguided “consistency check” from the answer. Sorry about that; not enough caffeine, I suppose.

[image: Three snapshots of the solution]

Comment: Sorry, you mean that $lim_{t\to+\infty}u(t,r)=1$ if $r=\beta$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: No, not all! By your own solution formula, $u(t,\beta)=u_0(\beta)e^{\alpha t}$, which goes to infinity if $u_0(\beta)>0$. For any $t>0$, the graph of $u(t,r)$ for $r\in[0,1]$ looks like a copy of the graph of $u_0$, squeezed in the horizontal direction down to size $e^{-\alpha t}$ but expanded in the vertical direction by the factor $e^{\alpha t}$, leaving the integral unchanged – joined by zero values on the left and right. (Assuming $\beta\in(0,1)$ and $\alpha>0$, which I forgot to mention.)

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your time!, Now I need to think a bit about your answer.

Comment: I have a question... Since $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$ I should have that $\int_0^1u(t,r)dr=1$, but if I write the expression of $u(t, r)$ in terms of $u_0$ and I change variable I get that $\int_0^1u(t,r)dr=\int_{\beta-\beta e^{\alpha t}}^{\beta-\beta e^{\alpha t}+1}u_0(r')dr'$ that in general is not $1$ unless $u_0$ is periodic... Is that correct?

Comment: Don't forget that $u(t,r)$ is zero outside a small interval (see the first formula in the answer). So you should integrate only over that interval before you apply the change of variables formula.

Comment: Yes, I agree! Thank you! The new interval in which I am integrarting is of lenght $e^{\alpha t}$ so it is larger than $1$. There is a mistake in my comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, another question. I am not able to understand how are you can conclude that $\lim_{t\to +\infty}u(t,r)=\delta_{\beta}(r)$... Is this a consequence of the fact that $\int_0^1u(t,r)dr=1$?

Comment: Hance-Olsen Could you give me an hint why $lim_{t\to+\infty}u(t,r)=\delta_{\beta}$? Sorry for if I am bothering you.

Comment: Basically, since it is a statement of distributions, the limit has to be taken in a weak sense. What you need to prove is that, for any infinitely differentiable function $f$, you have $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_0^1 u(t,r)f(r)\,dr=f(p)$. In this case, you only need the continuity of $f$. Since $\int_0^1 u(t,r)\,dr=1$, and $u(t,r)$ is nonzero only in a small interval shrinking towards $\{p\}$, you will find that $f(r)\approx f(p)$ whenever $u(t,r)\ne0$ and $t$ is large. The technical details are too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: But this is a *very* standard type of argument in the theory of distributions.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! Now I think I understood!